# Braintree partial settlement not working

Tags: php, braintree

Braintree Partial Settlement not working for this code .If I write this code the page set blank with no error or no message.

```
Braintree\Transaction::submitForPartialSettlement('transaction_id', '10.00');
```

please give answer if anyone have idea.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple partial settlements are only available for PayPal transactions.

```
$result = Braintree_Transaction::submitForPartialSettlement('theParentAuthTransactionId', '10.00');

    if ($result->success) {
        $settledTransaction = $result->transaction;
    } else {
        print_r($result->errors);
    }
```